# Python Path Still Working When Commented Out

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have python 3.7.8 installed on my mac (Big Sur OS). I had originally set my path in .zprofile thinking my system needed it to find python 3.7. However, when I comment out the path, and type 'python3' in a newly sourced terminal, it loads python 3.7 perfectly. How is this possible? Is it reading the path from somewhere else? I even made sure it was commented out in zprofile_backup.

Here is what my .zprofile looks like (I commented out everything to try to get the python3 command to fail):

```
# pyspark
#export SPARK_HOME=/Users/user.name/spark-3.0.1-bin-without-hadoop
#export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
#export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3

# hadoop
#export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/user.name/hadoop-2.8.5

# Jupyter (append to end of path)
#export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin

# Python 3.7 for user system python
# export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python3:$PATH
```

Comment: Your PATH may be set somewhere else. What does `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: It returns: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin - and that's with my .zprofile as is above.